# Tokenizing a string gives some words merged

Tags: python, stdin

I use the following code to tokenize a string,read from stdin.

```
d=[]
cur = ''
for i in sys.stdin.readline():
    if i in ' .':
        if cur not in d and (cur != ''):
            d.append(cur)
            cur = ''
    else:
        cur = cur + i.lower()
```

This gives me a array of non repeating words.However, in my output,Some of the words dont get split.

My Input is

```
Dan went to the north pole to lead an expedition during summer.
```

And the output array d is

['dan', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'north', 'pole', 'tolead', 'an', 'expedition', 'during', 'summer']

Why is `tolead` together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
d=[]
cur = ''
for i in sys.stdin.readline():
    if i in ' .':
        if cur not in d and (cur != ''):
            d.append(cur)
        cur = '' # note the different indentation
    else:
        cur = cur + i.lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for line in sys.stdin.readline():
    res = set(word.lower() for word in line[:-1].split(" "))
    print res
```

Example:

```
line = "Dan went to the north pole to lead an expedition during summer."
res = set(word.lower() for word in line[:-1].split(" "))
print res

set(['north', 'lead', 'expedition', 'dan', 'an', 'to', 'pole', 'during', 'went', 'summer', 'the'])
```

After comments, I edit: this solution preserves input order and filters separators

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict
line = "Dan went to the north pole to lead an expedition during summer."
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(re.findall(r"[\w']+", line)))
# ['Dan', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'north', 'pole', 'lead', 'an', 'expedition', 'during', 'summer']
```

Comment: Should probably also split on . just to make sure it's true to OPs question.

Comment: Done with line[:-1] :)

Comment: Well no, not quite, because you could potentially have multiple sentences. Just because it works on the OPs example doesn't mean it works in the wild.

Comment: space is not the only thing that demarcates my words,any kind of punctuation can..

Comment: Please see my Edition, with any separator and preserving order

Answer (score 1):

`"to"` is already in `"d"`. So, your loop skips the space in between `"to"` and `"lead"`, but continues concatenating; once it gets to the next space, it sees that `"tolead"` isn't in `d`, so it appends it.

Easier solution; it also strips ALL forms of punctuation:

```
>>> import string
>>> set("Dan went to the north pole to lead an expedition during summer.".translate(None, string.punctuation).lower().split())
set(['summer', 'north', 'lead', 'expedition', 'dan', 'an', 'to', 'pole', 'during', 'went', 'the'])
```